# C++ Sum of factorial -Request 2nd code

Tags: c++, factorial

I would like to analyze the complexity of my code algorithm.Therefore,i must have 2 different programs giving the same functions to allow me to start off.

Currently this is my own code.

I'm not sure if it is allowed that i would like to have someone that could volunteer his own way code to compute summation of factorial for me as the 2nd program code.

Preferrably a nested loop.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    int val;
    int i;
    int a = 0;
    int c = 1;
    cout << "Please enter a number: ";
    cin >> val;
    cout << endl;

    for (i = 1; i <= val; i++)
    {
        c = c * i;
        a = a + c;
    }
    cout << "The sum of the factorials is " << a << endl;

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: "must have 2 different programs". No, not really. What would you do with the second program?

Comment: I don't get it. You want a program that computes the sum of factorials written by someone else?

Comment: Calculating the complexity does not require a second program to compare against.

Comment: question given were asking me to get 2 programs with different complexities.So,my thinking was to get 2 different coding.

Comment: i shall analyze (i.e. by theoretical analysis) the complexity of the algorithms by finding the Big-Oh notation. Plz correct me if I were wrong on understand the question.TQ

Comment: You should check whether this is allowed before asking. Now that you've asked, you are at risk of having violated your school's academic honesty code.

Answer (score 1):

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    int val;
    cout << "Please enter a number: ";
    cin >> val;
    cout << endl;

    static const int results[] = {
       0, 1, 3, 9, 33, 153, 873, 5913, 46233, 409113,
       4037913, 43954713, 522956313
    };

    cout << "The sum of the factorials is " << results[val < 0 ? 0 : val] << endl;

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Note that I replicated the defect in the original program which causes it to return the incorrect value if the user enters `0`.

This alternate version assumes 32-bit integers because it takes advantage of overflow behavior. Extending to 64-bit integers is left as an exercise.

Answer (score 0):

I do not understand what you do with another nested way but i hope this can help...

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int val;
    int i;
    int a = 0;
    int c = 1;
    cout << "Please enter a number: ";
    cin >> val;
    cout << endl;

    for (i = 1; i <= val; i++){
        c *= i;
        a += c;
    }
    int c2=1;
    for (i = val; i > 1; i--){
        c2*=i;
        c2++;
    }

    cout << "The sum of the factorials is " << a << endl;
    cout << "The sum of the factorials is " << c2 << endl;

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    #include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int suma = 0;
    int n = 0;

    cout << "Sum of factorials\n";
    cout << "-------------------------------\n";
    cout << "Insert number of n: ";
    cin >> n;

    int i = 1;
    while (i <= n)
    {
        int factorial = 1;
        for(int j=1; j<=i; j++)
        {
            factorial = factorial * j;
        }

        suma += factorial;
        i++;
    }

    cout << "Sum of factorials is: " << suma;

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please don't answer just with source code. Try to provide a nice description about how your solution works. See: [stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). Thanks!